# launching TestNG classes

Tags: testng

Im having trouble with lanching a TestNG class.
when i hit runqdebug it says o the bottom screen "Launcing 'TestNme'.."
but it keep gettingstuck  57% and my only option is to shut down eclipse.
Thia problem only accurs when launhing the tests from a specific project.
What could be the possible reason for te test to run from one project but not the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have a testng.jar file on the build classpath of your project? That's usually the reason for this problem.

The TestNG Eclipse plug-in has its own, so you can remove the one you have and it should fix your problem.

I'll try to improve the plug-in to avoid this problem but I'm not 100% positive it's possible.